# error: expected unqualified-id before string constant extern "a" {

Tags: c++

So, this problem, for some reason it shows me this error (ubuntu, terminal, g++).  I searched the net and didn't show anything similar to mine. The code is (gfdz.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct dynmass
{
    unsigned long int vm; //вместимость
    unsigned long int el; //количество элементов
};

int *i,*q;

void create()
{
    dynmass a;
    a.vm = 0;
    a.el = 0;
    i = new int[0];

    extern "a" 
    {
        void push();
        void remuve();
        int kolichestvo();
        int vmestimostb();
        int main;
    };
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't know how to make it look normal

Comment: What do you expect `extern "a"` to do?

Comment: It looks like you're in urgent need of one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a language linkage specification. And within it, you have a bunch of function declarations.

A language specifications can only appear in namespace scope. Yours is in the block scope, so that's what's wrong with it. Also, "a" language linkage is not supported by standard c++ so you may need to consult your compiler manual to find out if it's supported.